# is it right to do using ui-router to activate menu items. Any advices to help me understand this?

Tags: angularjs, menu, menuitem, angular-ui-router

What I did is:
When a menu item is clicked, a action will be done, like deleting a user, sending emails to a group, etc. To this end, for each menu item, I define a ui-router state, and use the state url to activate the state via sref. I thought that a menu action is just a UI component for user to let users to do something, which is just a state of UI.

I was advised that I was using ui-router in a wrong way as a state url can not identify an action. For example, to delete a group of users, the state url can not tell you what group of users have been deleted.

Comment: He made confusion about ui-route and RESTful... please, explain to him about RESTful

Answer (score 1):

In short, I agree with your manager while being an angular newbie myself. Angular routes are designed for managing different views of your app. I.e. define a route and corresponding view template for each view. If you add application logic into the routes, your application structure gets quickly a mess and difficult to keep clear.

To me it is much more natural that the views are managed by the routes, and each action in each view is handled by the controller of that view. If the actions grow "big", then it is worth refactoring parts of the controller into separate services. If you require some sort of "dynamic HTML" depending on the action, e.g. bootstrap modals are handy for doing that within the current view (see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

E.g. in my current project, I don't actually manually edit the routes at all but let yeoman angular generator to do that for me free of charge - i.e. I instantiate each new view in my dev.env using the following command (more info on this from https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)

```
yo angular:route myNewView
```

More info on angular philosophy can be read from angular documentation for developers: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing this actions via a method on $scope.

```
$scope.deleteItem = function (items) {
  Service.delete(items);
};
// which is the same as:
$scope.deleteItem = Service.delete;

<a ng-click="deleteItem(item)">Delete This Item</a>
```

Having it in the URL just seems wrong. I mean what does that look like? www.mysite.com/delete/users?